# External library throws undefined reference errors in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator

I have some problems with using an external library/SDK.
I am using Qt Creator under Ubuntu with the Oculus Rift SDK. The Oculus Rift SDK consists of a platform dependent lib file and some c++ source code. Note that I highly doubt my problem is in any way specific to the Oculus SDK or Xinerama.

I used the wizard and added the SDK as an external library. This was the result:

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../OculusSDK/LibOVR/Lib/Linux/Release/x86_64/ -lovr
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../OculusSDK/LibOVR/Include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../OculusSDK/LibOVR/Include
unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../OculusSDK/LibOVR/Lib/Linux/Release/x86_64/libovr.a
```

Now I should be able to call methods from the SDK. However, this is one of the errors I get while compiling:

```
/home/me/OculusSDK/LibOVR/Lib/Linux/Release/x86_64/libovr.a(OVR_Linux_HMDDevice.o):-1: In function `OVR::Linux::HMDDeviceFactory::EnumerateDevices(OVR::DeviceFactory::EnumerateVisitor&)':
OVR_Linux_HMDDevice.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `XineramaIsActive'
```

I already tried adding this line to my .pro file but nothing changed:

```
unix:LIBS += -lXinerama
```

If I include the very same header file as OVR_Linux_HMDDevice.cpp does,

```
#include <X11/extensions/Xinerama.h>
```

I can successfully call XineramaIsActive from my code. So apparently, it's just the external source code that has issues accessing the method.

Any ideas what changes I have to make to the build process for this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link order is important here. You need to make sure the `-lXinerama` option is added *after* the `-lovr` option. qmake should preserve the order of libraries as you add them in your `.pro` file.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter) for more information.

Comment: I indeed added -lXinerama before -lovr. After moving it down and adding another library, it finally compiled. Thank you so much! But I realize I am lacking some very basic understanding here: Intuition tells me it should come first, so why is it the other way round?

Comment: Dependencies are resolved left to right. So if you do `-la -lb -lc`, `libb` will be used to resolve undefined symbols in `liba`, and `libc` will be used to resolve dependencies in `liba` and `libb`. If, say, `liba` depends on `libb`, `libb` depends on `libc`, and `libc` depends on `liba`... you will have to "link" `liba` twice: `-la -lb -lc -la`. This leads to funny situations. Note that GNU binutils has the options `--begin-group` and `--end-group` which do search circularly until dependencies are resolved. In principle though, this circular search could lead to a deadlock.

Comment: Thank you again! Thinking about it, this makes a lot more sense.