# Undefined reference to 'XtInitialize'

Tags: c, linux, x11

I am trying to compile and link an `Athena` Xt program on `Ubuntu` linux.

I have compiled program into an object file but I am unable to link it with Xt library no matter what.

My linker call is

```
ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.a program.o
```

I am getting this linker error

```
program.o: In function `main':
program.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `XtInitialize'
program.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `commandWidgetClass'
program.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `XtCreateManagedWidget'
program.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `XtStrings'
program.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `XtAddCallback'
program.c:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `XtRealizeWidget'
program.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `XtMainLoop'
```

I probed `Xt` library with `nm` and symbols are there:

```
nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.a | grep XtInitialize
                 U _XtInitializeActionData
0000000000000360 T XtInitializeWidgetClass
00000000000018b0 T XtInitialize
                 U XtInitializeWidgetClass
00000000000006d0 T _XtInitializeActionData
                 U XtInitializeWidgetClass
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: how about putting the library after the object file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ld  program.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.a
```

argument order to ld matters, it expects to find the library after the object file with the reference.