# Including shared library via symlink results in undefined reference

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to use a shared library (to which I don't know the source code). However I struggle with linking it into my project. The library contains an API for a camera driver, which is pretty much a bunch of functions thrown together (as far as I can see there is no structure).

The library (and two symlinks to it) are located in /usr/lib and are called

```
libueye_api64.so.4.72 - the library
libueye_api.so.1      - a symlink pointing to above library
libueye_api.so        - another symlink pointing to libueye_api64.so.4.72
```

there also is a header file located in /usr/include named `ueye.h` which is the header file for the library (at least I assume that).

Using the simple example `mwe.cpp`

```
#include "ueye.h"
int main()
{
    int device_count = 0;
    int error_value = is_GetNumberOfCameras(&device_count);
    return 0;
}
```

which I tried to compile (successful) and link, I got the following:

```
~/Documents/mwe$ g++ -I/usr/include -c mwe.cpp
~/Documents/mwe$ g++ -L/usr/lib -lueye_api mwe.o -o test
mwe.o: In function `main':
mwe.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `is_GetNumberOfCameras'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which should mean that either `is_GetNumberOfCameras` is not implemented in the library or I have some scoping issue. In any way the linker can't find an implementation for this function (which is part of the API according to the documentation).
I further dumped the list of all symbols in the .so using

```
readelf -Ws /usr/lib/libueye_api64.so.4.72
```

which has the symbol I am looking for:

```
980: 00000000003372b0     5 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 is_GetNumberOfCameras
```

This makes me wonder why I can't find it. Am I including the wrong library? I tried compiling with `ueye_api64` but this would just return `cannot find library`. So, what am I missing?

Edit: I should also mention, that I am doing this under Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) using gcc, which you probably figured out by now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib -lueye_api mwe.o -o test
```

To:

```
g++ mwe.o -o test -L/usr/lib -lueye_api
```

You can look at this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter) to understand why the order is important. The accepted answer gives a great explanation.

The main idea is that the linker checks library to resolve currently unresolved symbols only once when it meets this library in the list of options.

But all options are processed consequently.

So if you put `-lueye_api` before `mwe.o` linker doesn't know about `mwe.o` and, of course, it doesn't try to resolve anything (in fact, he hasn't any symbols to resolve).

From the other side, if you put `-lueye_api` after `mwe.o` linker firstly add all unresolved symbols from `mwe.o`to the list of unresolved symbols and after that resolves all of them using `ueye_api` library successfully.

Finally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) is another good discussion that will be helpful for you.

Comment: explain why this should help

Comment: This links successfully. What I don't understand is why. Aren't the arguments read from left to right, meaning that I have to specify the library before my *.o?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger No, the other way around. You must specify the library/object file that resolves symbols to the right of library/object file that uses them.