# Working with Influxdb connection in C Programming raising undefined referece to influxdb_client_new

Tags: c, gcc

This is `main.c` file I am trying to work with `influxdb` library I hope I installed it clearly with my knowledge here are the screen shots of library 
[image]
This is linked library

[image]
This is the path of the library

This is the code file

```
#include <influxdb/influxdb.h>

int main() {
    int status;
    s_influxdb_client *client = influxdb_client_new("xxxxxxxxxx", "influxdb", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "", 0);

    status = influxdb_create_database(client, "toto");

    influxdb_client_free(client);

    return status != 201;
}
```

This is how I executing the command in gcc to compile and run

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -linfluxdb -o john john.c
```

Even though I included the library it raising undefined reference
This is what my error is

```
/tmp/cce9K1Kh.o: In function `main':
john.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `influxdb_client_new'
john.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `influxdb_create_database'
john.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `influxdb_client_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is where I found library  and Followed the instructions in `Read Me` file Everything is performed smooth [Influxdb](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-c)

Please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

The `influxdb` [`README.md`](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-c/blob/master/README.md) is b0rken. [Ordering of command-line arguments to `gcc` (or the linker actually) matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter); the `-linfluxdb` must come **after** your `john.c` on the command line.

Thus, try compiling/linking with with

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -o john john.c -linfluxdb
```

Comment: Successfully compiled but when I execute `./john` it is raising following exception `./john: error while loading shared libraries: libinfluxdb.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: can u suggest me alternate for influxdb

Comment: it asked me for including the `-lcurl` so i edited your answer for just small change