# Poco library linking errors in ubuntu platform

Tags: c++, linux, g++, poco, poco-libraries

I have downloaded the latest Poco library poco-1.7.3.tar. Configured with few properties and did make install.
Tried the following sample helloworld program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Util/Application.h>

class HelloPocoApplication : public Poco::Util::Application
{
protected:
    virtual int main(const std::vector<std::string> &args)
    {
            std::cout << "Hello, POCO C++ Libraries!" << std::endl;

            return EXIT_OK;
    }
};
POCO_APP_MAIN(HelloPocoApplication);
```

Compiled it using

> g++ -I poco-1.7.3/Util/include -I poco-1.7.3/XML/include -I poco-1.7.3/JSON/include -I poco-1.7.3/Foundation/include -L poco-1.7.3/lib/Linux/x86_64 -lPocoUtil -lPocoFoundation -lPocoXML -lPocoJSON helloworld.cpp -o prog

But it is throwing following errors

```
 /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o: In function `main':
 helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to     `Poco::Util::Application::init(int, char**)'
      helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to    `Poco::Logger::log(Poco::Exception const&)'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o: In function `Poco::RefCountedObject::release() const':
    helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZNK4Poco16RefCountedObject7releaseEv[_ZNK4Poco16RefCountedObject7releaseEv]+0x6e): undefined reference to `Poco::Bugcheck::unexpected(char const*, int)'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o: In function `Poco::Util::Application::logger() const':
    helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZNK4Poco4Util11Application6loggerEv[_ZNK4Poco4Util11Application6loggerEv]+0x2c): undefined reference to `Poco::Bugcheck::nullPointer(char const*, char const*, int)'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o: In function `HelloPocoApplication::HelloPocoApplication()':
    helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN20HelloPocoApplicationC2Ev[_ZN20HelloPocoApplicationC5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::Application()'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x2c): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Exception'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o: In function `Poco::AutoPtr<HelloPocoApplication>::operator->()':
    helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco7AutoPtrI20HelloPocoApplicationEptEv[_ZN4Poco7AutoPtrI20HelloPocoApplicationEptEv]+0x3a): undefined reference to `Poco::NullPointerException::NullPointerException(int)'
    helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco7AutoPtrI20HelloPocoApplicationEptEv[_ZN4Poco7AutoPtrI20HelloPocoApplicationEptEv]+0x3f): undefined reference to `Poco::NullPointerException::~NullPointerException()'
    helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco7AutoPtrI20HelloPocoApplicationEptEv[_ZN4Poco7AutoPtrI20HelloPocoApplicationEptEv]+0x44): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::NullPointerException'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o:(.rodata._ZTV20HelloPocoApplication[_ZTV20HelloPocoApplication]+0x20): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::name() const'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o:(.rodata._ZTV20HelloPocoApplication[_ZTV20HelloPocoApplication]+0x28): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::initialize(Poco::Util::Application&)'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o:(.rodata._ZTV20HelloPocoApplication[_ZTV20HelloPocoApplication]+0x30): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::uninitialize()'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o:(.rodata._ZTV20HelloPocoApplication[_ZTV20HelloPocoApplication]+0x38): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::reinitialize(Poco::Util::Application&)'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o:(.rodata._ZTV20HelloPocoApplication[_ZTV20HelloPocoApplication]+0x40): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::defineOptions(Poco::Util::OptionSet&)'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o:(.rodata._ZTV20HelloPocoApplication[_ZTV20HelloPocoApplication]+0x48): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::run()'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o:(.rodata._ZTV20HelloPocoApplication[_ZTV20HelloPocoApplication]+0x50): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::handleOption(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o: In function `HelloPocoApplication::~HelloPocoApplication()':
    helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN20HelloPocoApplicationD2Ev[_ZN20HelloPocoApplicationD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::~Application()'
    /tmp/ccFvl4ll.o:(.rodata._ZTI20HelloPocoApplication[_ZTI20HelloPocoApplication]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Util::Application'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to run exactly that code but using CMake rather than Makefile and it worked. you have just to change the paths according to your machine.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(tutocpp14)

set(Poco_DIR "/usr/local/lib/cmake/Poco/") 
set(Poco_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/Poco/")

find_package(Poco REQUIRED COMPONENTS Foundation Net XML Util) # add other components here

# check c++11 / c++0x
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11 " COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

include_directories( ${Poco_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 

add_executable(publisher src/publisher.cpp)
target_link_libraries(publisher ${Poco_LIBRARIES})
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Checking with Poco documents it seems it should work. Looking at an example [here](https://github.com/wancw/poco-examples/tree/master/190-Applications/hello-world), and its [makefile](https://github.com/wancw/poco-examples/blob/master/190-Applications/hello-world/Makefile), I suspect the order of your library is reversed. Assuming that paths are correct (since ld didn't report on that) I would say that linking order is incorrect. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter) Why.
So I suggest you change your command to

`g++ -I poco-1.7.3/Util/include -I poco-1.7.3/Foundation/include -L poco-1.7.3/lib/Linux/x86_64 -lPocoFoundation -lPocoUtil  helloworld.cpp -o prog`

in case those examples goes out of scope somehow in future, here is the code and makefile copied.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Util/Application.h>

class HelloPocoApplication : public Poco::Util::Application
{
protected:
    virtual int main(const std::vector<std::string> &args)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, POCO C++ Libraries!" << std::endl;

        return EXIT_OK;
    }
};

POCO_APP_MAIN(HelloPocoApplication);
```

**Note:** Remember to restore the tabs instead of spaces in makefile code!

```
POCO_LIBS=-lPocoFoundation -lPocoUtil

all: hello-poco

clean:
    rm -f hello-poco

hello-poco: hello-poco.cpp
    $(CXX) $(POCO_LIBS) -o hello-poco hello-poco.cpp
```

**Update:**

With all above said, I have to put a note on strangeness of your error especially Poco::Logger which is found in [foundation](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Logger.html) library. So it seems that library does not get linked. I would suggest two things:
1. Check if its not corrupted. You can do that by cleaning and recompiling
2. Try to install in standard path so that you avoid linking paths

I know all these are not definitive (guess works at best) but will be useful to provide you hints of where the issue lies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First method of changing order of linking reported the same issue.

Comment: Second method: From where the program can pick the included files like Application.h. It is reporting the obvious error as follows. **'$ make'
g++ -lPocoFoundation -lPocoUtil -o hello-poco hello-poco.cpp
hello-poco.cpp:2:35: fatal error: Poco/Util/Application.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Poco/Util/Application.h>
                                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [hello-poco] Error 1**

Comment: looking at samples make I don't see anything peculiar than two additional libraries. See it here. https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Util/samples/SampleApp/Makefile

Can you compile samples and see if they run correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your original library linking order was fine, but you are missing XML and JSON (Util depends on these libraries). Although, the link errors you've got indicate that you may be either missing Foundation library or mixing library versions.

```
$ echo $POCO_BASE
/tmp/poco
$ pwd
/tmp/poco/test
$ g++ -I $POCO_BASE/Util/include -I $POCO_BASE/Foundation/include -L $POCO_BASE/lib/Linux/x86_64 -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -lPocoJSON -lPocoFoundation helloworld.cpp -o prog
```

Comment: It reduced the errors. But still reporting following issues.  **/tmp/ccjBEy6m.o: In function `main':
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::init(int, char**)'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `Poco::Logger::log(Poco::Exception const&)'
/tmp/ccjBEy6m.o: In function `Poco::RefCountedObject::release() const':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZNK4Poco16RefCountedObject7releaseEv[_ZNK4Poco16RefCou(.rodata._ZTV20HelloPocoApplication[_ZTV20HelloPocoApplication]+0x
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Comment: You are either (a) missing poco libraries, or (b) linking your application with different standard library than the one with which poco libraries are linked

Answer (score 0):

try this command to compile.

> g++ <src_file>.cpp -lPocoFoundation  -lPocoJSON -lPocoUtil -lPocoJWT
> -o <binary_name>