# make: create a test binary for each file in test directory

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple structure as below for a small library I'm building.

- I want `make build` to build the library (`libproj.a`) from sources under `./source`
- I want `make build_test` to build every source file under `./test` prefixed with `test_` into it's own binary

I can build the library `libproj.a` just fine, but can't figure out how to build the tests. I'm currently getting the following linker error when attempting to build `/cygdrive/d/Source/proj/build/obj/test_proj.o:test_proj.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to 'test'`.

**Directory structure**

```
+---build
|   +---lib
|   +---obj
|   \---test
+---include
|   \---proj
+---source
\---test
```

**Makefile**

```
PROJECT             = proj
LIBNAME             = lib$(PROJECT).a

CFLAGS              = -Wall -Wextra -O0

DIR_ROOT            = $(abspath .)
DIR_SRC_LIB         = $(DIR_ROOT)/source
DIR_SRC_TEST        = $(DIR_ROOT)/test

DIR_BLD_OBJ         = $(DIR_ROOT)/build/obj
DIR_BLD_LIB         = $(DIR_ROOT)/build/lib
DIR_BLD_TEST        = $(DIR_ROOT)/build/test

LST_OBJ_LIB         = $(patsubst $(DIR_SRC_LIB)/%.c, $(DIR_BLD_OBJ)/%.o, $(wildcard $(DIR_SRC_LIB)/*.c))
LST_OBJ_TEST        = $(patsubst $(DIR_SRC_TEST)/%.c, $(DIR_BLD_OBJ)/%.o, $(wildcard $(DIR_SRC_TEST)/*.c))
LST_BIN_TEST        = $(patsubst $(DIR_SRC_TEST)/%.c, $(DIR_BLD_TEST)/%, $(wildcard $(DIR_SRC_TEST)/test_*.c))

INCLUDES            = -I $(DIR_ROOT)/include

clean:
    $(RM) $(LST_OBJ_LIB)
    $(RM) $(LST_OBJ_TEST)

build:
    $(info build)

build-test: $(LST_BIN_TEST)
    $(info build-test)

run-test:
    $(info run-test)

install:
    $(info install)

$(LIBNAME): $(LST_OBJ_LIB)
    $(AR) rvs $(DIR_BLD_LIB)/$@ $^

$(DIR_BLD_OBJ)/%.o: $(DIR_SRC_LIB)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

$(DIR_BLD_TEST)/%: $(DIR_BLD_OBJ)/%.o $(LIBNAME)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -L $(DIR_BLD_LIB) -l $(PROJECT) $< -o $@

$(DIR_BLD_OBJ)/%.o: $(DIR_SRC_TEST)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Into what kind of binary do you want to build those test files? Into separate executables? Or object files that are linked into something else?

Comment: @GeorgP. separate executables, yes. named test_libproj, test_mytest for example (if that's the corresponding source files names).

Comment: @GeorgP. Added more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this line:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -L $(DIR_BLD_LIB) -l $(PROJECT) $< -o $@
```

is wrong. You're passing to the compiler (I'm assuming gcc) the libraries before the object files. If your compiler acts as gcc does, the code in the libraries is getting discarded because it hasn't been referenced yet when it parses them [see -l option documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

It should be

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -L $(DIR_BLD_LIB) $< -l $(PROJECT) -o $@
```

(Note the changed position of `$<`)

Furthermore, remeber that the order of libraries is important: see this excellent [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894098/3914029).