# Why Do I Get Undefined Reference When -L And -l Look Correct

Tags: c, mingw, static-linking

I am using [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) on a Windows 8.1 machine and I'm trying to reference a static library.  Try as I might I get an undefined reference error.

This is usually just a case of passing the `-L` and `-l` flags normally right but here is what I do...

I have the following directory structure:

```
myapp.c
mylib
    mylib.c
    mylib.h
```

### mylib/mylib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void do_something_amazing(void) {
    printf("Woah\n");
}
```

### mylib/mylib.h

```
void do_something_amazing(void);
```

### myapp.c

```
#include "mylib/mylib.h"

int main() {
    do_something_amazing();
    return (0);
}
```

I run the following commands to first create a `libmylib` static library then to build the `myapp` that references it:

```
gcc -c -o mylib/mylib.o mylib/mylib.c
ar rcs mylib/libmylib.a mylib/mylib.o
gcc -Lmylib -lmylib myapp.c
```

And the last finishes with this error:

```
cchqpYVl.o:myapp.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `do_something_amazing'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This seems kind of basic, so I am sure I am being silly and I missed a step - any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Put `-lmylib` after `myapp.c` in the last command. It links in order without a second pass by default

Comment: Ugh, THANK YOU!  Cannot believe I did not try that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter