# How to solve this error in C ffmpeg?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, centos

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FZpO.png)

---

Here are my linker options :

```
-lavformat
-lavcodec
-lswscale
-lavutil
-lavfilter
-lswresample
-lpostproc
-lpthread
-lz
-lx264
-lx265
-lrt
-ldl
-lGL
-lm
-lavdevice
-lvorbis
-lxcb
```

Comment: Missing libraries!! What is the location of `libxcb`, `libfreetype` etc.

Comment: Ok, and where is the error message?

Comment: Where did you put your libraries ? Maybe you have to think about adding the full path usin -L

Comment: @Michi There is a very small link, you can barely notice in the very beginning of the post [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FZpO.png)  :-D :-D

Comment: For GCC the order of libraries is important. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter

Comment: Error messages are text messages. Do not post text as graphics link!.

Comment: Thanks to everyone I corrected it

Comment: @GauravPathak I was on the Phone and I did not noticed. Tnx :)

Comment: If you got a fix, post it as an answer to your own question here.