# Building Kafka with OpenSSL for MacOS

Tags: macos, c++11, openssl, apache-kafka, static-linking

I'm trying to build a C++ static Kafka library for MacOS using this implementation: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka

I want to include encryption so I'm trying to link in OpenSSL. My build script looks as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git
cd librdkafka
git checkout b581d0d9df282847f76e8b9e87337161959d39c9

./configure --prefix=$ARTIFACT_DIR \
  --CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" \
  --LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" \
  --enable-static
make
make install
```

I upload the resulting artifact to a bucket where I then reference in my project that I manage using Bazel(https://bazel.build). In my main I have some basic code that I'm using to test that Kafka was built correctly and it keeps crashing. Here what my main looks like:

```
#include <librdkafka/rdkafkacpp.h>

int main() {
  RdKafka::Conf *conf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_GLOBAL);
  RdKafka::Conf *tconf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_TOPIC);
}
```

When I attempt to run this program I get the follow linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sasl_client_init", referenced from:
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_global_init in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
  "_sasl_client_new", referenced from:
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_client_new in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
     (maybe you meant: _rd_kafka_sasl_client_new)
  "_sasl_client_start", referenced from:
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_client_new in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
  "_sasl_client_step", referenced from:
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_recv in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
  "_sasl_dispose", referenced from:
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_close in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
  "_sasl_errdetail", referenced from:
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_client_new in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_recv in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
  "_sasl_errstring", referenced from:
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_global_init in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_client_new in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
  "_sasl_getprop", referenced from:
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_recv in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
  "_sasl_listmech", referenced from:
      _rd_kafka_sasl_cyrus_client_new in librdkafka.a(rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

If I'm reading this error correctly it looks like OpenSSL is not being linked into the static library.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Output from command line to show what is happening during compilation.

```
using cache file config.cache
checking for OS or distribution... ok (osx)
checking for C compiler from CC env... failed
checking for gcc (by command)... ok (cached)
checking for C++ compiler from CXX env... failed
checking for C++ compiler (g++)... ok (cached)
checking executable ld... ok (cached)
checking executable nm... ok (cached)
checking executable objdump... ok (cached)
checking executable strip... ok (cached)
checking for debug symbols compiler flag (-g...)... ok (cached)
checking for pkgconfig (by command)... failed
checking for install (by command)... failed
checking for PIC (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for GNU-compatible linker options... failed
checking for OSX linker options... ok (cached)
checking for GNU linker-script ld flag... failed
checking for Solaris linker-script ld flag... failed (ignore)
checking for __atomic_32 (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for __atomic_64 (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for socket (by compile)... ok (cached)
parsing version '0x000b03ff'... ok (0.11.3)
checking for libpthread (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for zlib (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for libcrypto (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for liblz4 (by compile)... failed (disable)
checking for libssl (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for libsasl2 (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for crc32chw (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for regex (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for librt (by compile)... failed
checking for strndup (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for strerror_r (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for libdl (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for nm (by env NM)... ok (cached)
Generated Makefile.config
Generated config.h

Configuration summary:
  prefix                   /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3
  ARCH                     x86_64
  CPU                      generic
  GEN_PKG_CONFIG           y
  ENABLE_DEVEL             n
  ENABLE_VALGRIND          n
  ENABLE_REFCNT_DEBUG      n
  ENABLE_SHAREDPTR_DEBUG   n
  ENABLE_LZ4_EXT           y
  ENABLE_SSL               y
  ENABLE_SASL              y
  CPPFLAGS                 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align
  LDFLAGS                  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
  MKL_APP_NAME             librdkafka
  MKL_APP_DESC_ONELINE     The Apache Kafka C/C++ library
  MKL_DISTRO               osx
  SOLIB_EXT                .dylib
  CC                       gcc
  CXX                      g++
  LD                       ld
  NM                       nm
  OBJDUMP                  objdump
  STRIP                    strip
  PKG_CONFIG               pkg-config
  INSTALL                  install
  HAS_LDFLAGS_STATIC       n
  LIB_LDFLAGS              -shared -dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name,$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(LIBFILENAME)
  RDKAFKA_VERSION_STR      0.11.3
  MKL_APP_VERSION          0.11.3
  LIBS                     -lpthread -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lsasl2 -ldl
  CXXFLAGS                 -Wno-non-virtual-dtor
  SYMDUMPER                $(NM) -g
  exec_prefix              /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3
  bindir                   /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/bin
  sbindir                  /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/sbin
  libexecdir               /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/libexec
  datadir                  /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/share
  sysconfdir               /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/etc
  sharedstatedir           /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/com
  localstatedir            /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/var
  libdir                   /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib
  includedir               /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/include
  infodir                  /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/info
  mandir                   /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/man
Generated config.cache

Now type 'make' to build
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka.c -o rdkafka.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_broker.c -o rdkafka_broker.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_msg.c -o rdkafka_msg.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_topic.c -o rdkafka_topic.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_conf.c -o rdkafka_conf.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_timer.c -o rdkafka_timer.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_offset.c -o rdkafka_offset.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_transport.c -o rdkafka_transport.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_buf.c -o rdkafka_buf.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_queue.c -o rdkafka_queue.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_op.c -o rdkafka_op.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_request.c -o rdkafka_request.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_cgrp.c -o rdkafka_cgrp.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_pattern.c -o rdkafka_pattern.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_partition.c -o rdkafka_partition.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_subscription.c -o rdkafka_subscription.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_assignor.c -o rdkafka_assignor.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_range_assignor.c -o rdkafka_range_assignor.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_roundrobin_assignor.c -o rdkafka_roundrobin_assignor.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_feature.c -o rdkafka_feature.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdcrc32.c -o rdcrc32.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c crc32c.c -o crc32c.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdaddr.c -o rdaddr.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdrand.c -o rdrand.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdlist.c -o rdlist.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c tinycthread.c -o tinycthread.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdlog.c -o rdlog.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdstring.c -o rdstring.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_event.c -o rdkafka_event.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_metadata.c -o rdkafka_metadata.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdregex.c -o rdregex.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdports.c -o rdports.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_metadata_cache.c -o rdkafka_metadata_cache.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdavl.c -o rdavl.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_sasl.c -o rdkafka_sasl.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_sasl_plain.c -o rdkafka_sasl_plain.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_interceptor.c -o rdkafka_interceptor.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_msgset_writer.c -o rdkafka_msgset_writer.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_msgset_reader.c -o rdkafka_msgset_reader.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdvarint.c -o rdvarint.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdbuf.c -o rdbuf.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdunittest.c -o rdunittest.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.c -o rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_sasl_scram.c -o rdkafka_sasl_scram.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c snappy.c -o snappy.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdgz.c -o rdgz.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_lz4.c -o rdkafka_lz4.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rddl.c -o rddl.o
gcc -MD -MP -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DLIBRDKAFKA_GIT_VERSION="\"v0.11.3\""  -c rdkafka_plugin.c -o rdkafka_plugin.o
Creating shared library librdkafka.1.dylib
gcc -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -shared -dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name,/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib/librdkafka.1.dylib rdkafka.o rdkafka_broker.o rdkafka_msg.o rdkafka_topic.o rdkafka_conf.o rdkafka_timer.o rdkafka_offset.o rdkafka_transport.o rdkafka_buf.o rdkafka_queue.o rdkafka_op.o rdkafka_request.o rdkafka_cgrp.o rdkafka_pattern.o rdkafka_partition.o rdkafka_subscription.o rdkafka_assignor.o rdkafka_range_assignor.o rdkafka_roundrobin_assignor.o rdkafka_feature.o rdcrc32.o crc32c.o rdaddr.o rdrand.o rdlist.o tinycthread.o rdlog.o rdstring.o rdkafka_event.o rdkafka_metadata.o rdregex.o rdports.o rdkafka_metadata_cache.o rdavl.o rdkafka_sasl.o rdkafka_sasl_plain.o rdkafka_interceptor.o rdkafka_msgset_writer.o rdkafka_msgset_reader.o rdvarint.o rdbuf.o rdunittest.o rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o rdkafka_sasl_scram.o snappy.o rdgz.o rdkafka_lz4.o xxhash.o lz4.o lz4frame.o lz4hc.o rddl.o rdkafka_plugin.o -o librdkafka.1.dylib -lpthread -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lsasl2 -ldl
Creating static library librdkafka.a
ar rcs librdkafka.a rdkafka.o rdkafka_broker.o rdkafka_msg.o rdkafka_topic.o rdkafka_conf.o rdkafka_timer.o rdkafka_offset.o rdkafka_transport.o rdkafka_buf.o rdkafka_queue.o rdkafka_op.o rdkafka_request.o rdkafka_cgrp.o rdkafka_pattern.o rdkafka_partition.o rdkafka_subscription.o rdkafka_assignor.o rdkafka_range_assignor.o rdkafka_roundrobin_assignor.o rdkafka_feature.o rdcrc32.o crc32c.o rdaddr.o rdrand.o rdlist.o tinycthread.o rdlog.o rdstring.o rdkafka_event.o rdkafka_metadata.o rdregex.o rdports.o rdkafka_metadata_cache.o rdavl.o rdkafka_sasl.o rdkafka_sasl_plain.o rdkafka_interceptor.o rdkafka_msgset_writer.o rdkafka_msgset_reader.o rdvarint.o rdbuf.o rdunittest.o rdkafka_sasl_cyrus.o rdkafka_sasl_scram.o snappy.o rdgz.o rdkafka_lz4.o xxhash.o lz4.o lz4frame.o lz4hc.o rddl.o rdkafka_plugin.o
Generating pkg-config file rdkafka.pc
Checking librdkafka integrity
librdkafka.1.dylib             OK
librdkafka.a                   OK
Symbol visibility              OK
Generating pkg-config file rdkafka++.pc
Checking librdkafka++ integrity
librdkafka++.1.dylib           OK
librdkafka++.a                 OK
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C examples
gcc -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I../src rdkafka_example.c -o rdkafka_example -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib \
        ../src/librdkafka.a -lpthread -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lsasl2 -ldl
# rdkafka_example is ready
#
# Run producer (write messages on stdin)
./rdkafka_example -P -t <topic> -p <partition>

# or consumer
./rdkafka_example -C -t <topic> -p <partition>

#
# More usage options:
./rdkafka_example -h
gcc -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I../src rdkafka_performance.c -o rdkafka_performance -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib \
        ../src/librdkafka.a -lpthread -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lsasl2 -ldl
# rdkafka_performance is ready
#
# Run producer
./rdkafka_performance -P -t <topic> -p <partition> -s <msgsize>

# or consumer
./rdkafka_performance -C -t <topic> -p <partition>

#
# More usage options:
./rdkafka_performance -h
g++ -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -I../src-cpp rdkafka_example.cpp -o rdkafka_example_cpp -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib \
        ../src-cpp/librdkafka++.a ../src/librdkafka.a -lpthread -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lsasl2 -ldl -lstdc++
gcc -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I../src rdkafka_consumer_example.c -o rdkafka_consumer_example -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib \
        ../src/librdkafka.a -lpthread -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lsasl2 -ldl
# rdkafka_consumer_example is ready
#
./rdkafka_consumer_example <topic[:part]> <topic2[:part]> ..

#
# More usage options:
./rdkafka_consumer_example -h
g++ -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -I../src-cpp rdkafka_consumer_example.cpp -o rdkafka_consumer_example_cpp -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib \
        ../src-cpp/librdkafka++.a ../src/librdkafka.a -lpthread -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lsasl2 -ldl -lstdc++
g++ -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -I../src-cpp kafkatest_verifiable_client.cpp -o kafkatest_verifiable_client -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib \
        ../src-cpp/librdkafka++.a ../src/librdkafka.a -lpthread -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lsasl2 -ldl -lstdc++
gcc -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -I../src rdkafka_simple_producer.c -o rdkafka_simple_producer -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib \
        ../src/librdkafka.a -lpthread -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lsasl2 -ldl
Updating
Checking  integrity
CONFIGURATION.md               OK
examples/rdkafka_example       OK
examples/rdkafka_performance   OK
examples/rdkafka_example_cpp   OK
Checking librdkafka integrity
librdkafka.1.dylib             OK
librdkafka.a                   OK
Symbol visibility              OK
Checking librdkafka++ integrity
librdkafka++.1.dylib           OK
librdkafka++.a                 OK
Install librdkafka to /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3
install -d $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/include/librdkafka ; \
    install -d $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib ; \
    install rdkafka.h $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/include/librdkafka ; \
    install librdkafka.a $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib ; \
    install librdkafka.1.dylib $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib ; \
    [ -f "rdkafka.pc" ] && ( \
        install -d $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib/pkgconfig ; \
        install -m 0644 rdkafka.pc $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib/pkgconfig \
    ) ; \
    (cd $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib && ln -sf librdkafka.1.dylib librdkafka.dylib)
Install librdkafka++ to /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3
install -d $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/include/librdkafka ; \
    install -d $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib ; \
    install rdkafkacpp.h $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/include/librdkafka ; \
    install librdkafka++.a $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib ; \
    install librdkafka++.1.dylib $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib ; \
    [ -f "rdkafka++.pc" ] && ( \
        install -d $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib/pkgconfig ; \
        install -m 0644 rdkafka++.pc $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib/pkgconfig \
    ) ; \
    (cd $DESTDIR/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/librdkafka-0.11.3/lib && ln -sf librdkafka++.1.dylib librdkafka++.dylib)
```

Comment: `sasl_*` is not from OpenSSL. It is from another [presumably missing] library. Show your link command. Also see [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11893996/608639) (but I am not sure it is a problem because we need to see your link command).

Comment: @jww I've added the output from compilation to the original post since it is quite long. What I find strange is that in the entries that have to do with linking I keep seeing 'shared' even though I configure it to build a static library. When I explicitly add --CFLAGS="-static" during configuration I get an error that tells me that library not found for -lcrt0.o. Googling this problem it's apparently not possibly to set the -static flag. Perhaps creating a static library is not possible on MacOS and even though I specify it on the command line it is just ignored.

Comment: I just rebuilt the Kafka library and I specified that I did not want sasl (--disable-sasl) and at runtime it still crashed. Not sure why it's trying to loading it when I told it I do not want to use it.

Comment: Install cyrus-sasl/libsasl2 on the target machine.

Comment: In my case, the problem was the library that comes in MacOs by default. I had to install openSSL independently and link to it (openssl@1.1 in my case). I think the problem is that you need to link that library when compiling your program. That's what solved this problem for me.