# C++ Boost: undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category() in Windows

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile this code in CodeBlocks

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{


  if ( !boost::filesystem::exists( "myfile.txt" ) )
{
  std::cout << "Can't find my file!" << std::endl;
}
}
```

With this compile flags:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -O3 -pedantic-errors -Wall -std=c++0x -lboost_system -IC:\Users\moe\Desktop\boost_1_67_0 -c C:\Users\moe\Desktop\oo\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
```

But I always receive this error:

```
boost::system::generic_category()
```

this is the error log, that i receive when i compile the code:

```
Untitled4.o: In function `boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const':
C:/Users/moe/Desktop/boost_1_67_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:733: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/Users/moe/Desktop/boost_1_67_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:736: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/Users/moe/Desktop/boost_1_67_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:748: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
Untitled4.o: In function `boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const':
C:/Users/moe/Desktop/boost_1_67_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:703: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/Users/moe/Desktop/boost_1_67_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:706: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
Untitled4.o: In function `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)':
C:/Users/moe/Desktop/boost_1_67_0/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:981: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
C:/Users/moe/Desktop/boost_1_67_0/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:981: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, int> const&)'
Untitled4.o: In function `boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
C:/Users/moe/Desktop/boost_1_67_0/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:446: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `boost::system` needs to be built and linked, it is one of the parts of boost that is not header only

Comment: But how I can do that ?

Comment: @UnholySheep: Landa uses `-lboost_system`

Comment: @ThomasSablik but the linker directory is not being specified (`-L`)

Comment: @UnholySheep: The error message for missing linker directory is `cannot find -lboost_system`

Answer (score 2):

Put the libraries at the end of the linker command line:

- [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter)

Comment: In this way

g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -O3 -pedantic-errors -Wall -std=c++0x -IC:\Users\moe\Desktop\boost_1_67_0 -c C:\Users\moe\Desktop\oo\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o  -lboost_system

Answer (score -1):

Since your erro log also contained these:

`` C:/Users/moe/Desktop/boost_1_67_0/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:981: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()' ``

It is clear that you also lack `-lboost_filesystem`.

So there is no use to just add `-lboost_system` to the g++ command.

You can add `-lboost_system -lboost_filesystem` to your g++ command.