# Unable to identify issue GNU archiver. Compiling with *.o works but libname.a dosen't

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-18.04, unix-ar

I'm trying to make a static library (.a) but facing issues that I'm unable to understand. So in brief compiling with `*.o` succeeds but archiving them using `ar` and then using the `.a` file to compile gives me an `undefined reference to 'symbol'` error.

So here is a simple code.

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    hello_world();
    return 0;
}
```

**hello_world.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void hello_world (void) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

Compile.

```
gcc -c -o hello_world.o hello_world.c
ar crs libhello.a hello_world.o
gcc libhello.a -o test test.c
```

gives me the error

```
/tmp/ccsO7AJl.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `hello_world'
```

Instead doing this works(Compiles and runs fine)

```
gcc -c -o hello_world.o hello_world.c
gcc hello_world.o -o test test.c
```

I have no idea what I have done wrong so any help is appreciated.

Comment: argument ordering!

Comment: Also, you're using an outdated GCC, it defaults to C89 with implicit function declarations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an almost duplicate of [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter) - but the behaviour can be replicated without the `-l` switch by specifying the archive name on command line.

The GNU linker as executed by GCC will, by default, link from left to right, and only use those `.o` files from the library archive that are needed to satisfy undefined references *so far*. Since your library *precedes* the main translation unit on the command line, `hello_world` is not required at the time the linker is processing it.

The solution is to mention the library *after* the translation units/object files that depend on it:

```
gcc -o test test.c libhello.a
```

Comment: Ohh. That worked. Guess it was a silly mistake on my part.