# How to fix 'sincos@@GLIBC_2.2.5' undefined reference for fftw3 library

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc, fftw

I have been trying to install and execute a c-program using fftw3 library on Ubuntu machine but getting this error so many times.

How to fix the error? Help is much appreciated.

latest source code was downloaded: http://www.fftw.org/download.html

Install commands:

```sh
  sudo -H ./configure --enable-float --enable-sse --enable-threads
  sudo -H make
  sudo -H make install
```

Trying to compile:

```
gcc -Wall -O3 -o jediconvolve jediconvolve.c -L /usr/local/lib -lm -lcfitsio -lfftw3f
```

Errors:

```
bhishan@jedisim_sources:gcc -Wall -O3 -o jediconvolve jediconvolve.c -L /usr/local/lib -lm -lcfitsio -lfftw3f
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3f.a(trig.o): undefined reference to symbol 'sincos@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

## file jediconvolve.c to test

https://pastebin.com/fHKwejj7

Comment: add `-ldl` after `-lm` to gcc

Comment: add `$ ldd --version` output to show actual linker version.

Comment: Try moving `-lm` after `-lfftw3f`

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter in SO explained why the order of `-l` option in GCC matters.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, Somehow it worked. This is a most strange thing I have ever found. Thanks again. I always thought I can put l-libraries in any order, but I was wrong.

Comment: @EsmaeelE `gcc -Wall -O3 -o jediconvolve jediconvolve.c -L /usr/local/lib -lm -ldl -lcfitsio -lfftw3f` gives the same error.

Comment: @EsmaeelE `$ldd --version`  gives `--version: command not found` There is no binary called ldd in my computer.