# Using cmake, how do I link with a version of zfs built from source

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linker, pthreads

## Question

### Description

Im trying to compile something and when that required libblkid, libudev, and pthreads. When I compile and link against liblkid and libudev I predictably get some errors about how it cant find pthreads functions. However, when I compile and link against liblkid, libudev, and pthreads, the linker complains that it can't find anything from liblkid and libudev.

### Errors

When compiling and linking *without* pthread

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../zfs/lib/libzfs_core.a(thread_pool.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_attr_setaffinity_np@@GLIBC_2.3.4'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

When compiling and linking *with* pthread

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../zfs/lib/libzfs.a(libzfs_util.o): in function `zfs_nicestrtonum':
/tmp/zfs/lib/libzfs/libzfs_util.c:1559: undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: ../zfs/lib/libzfs.a(libzfs_changelist.o): in function `changelist_prefix':
/tmp/zfs/lib/libzfs/libzfs_changelist.c:107: undefined reference to `uu_avl_walk_start'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/zfs/lib/libzfs/libzfs_changelist.c:110: undefined reference to `uu_avl_walk_next'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/zfs/lib/libzfs/libzfs_changelist.c:152: undefined reference to `uu_avl_walk_end'
/usr/bin/ld: ../zfs/lib/libzfs.a(libzfs_changelist.o): in function `changelist_postfix':
/tmp/zfs/lib/libzfs/libzfs_changelist.c:186: undefined reference to `uu_avl_last'
...
```

### Replicating my work

I did this while compiling zfs from source so making a minimal example is beyond me. However, I bundled everything into a docker container.

`docker run -ti --rm failuregod/example` to run the container

I used cmake for this example and the docker container will drop you in the build folder.
`make nothread VERBOSE=1` builds without pthread and will print the gcc command that was run.
`make thread VERBOSE=1` builds with pthread and will print the gcc command that was run.

---

## This is not a duplicate

This is not a duplicate question because it is not asking "what does undefined reference mean". This question is asking "how do I link to this version of libzfs that I built from source." So answers like "well just include the right libraries in the right order" are unhelpful. A good answer would tell me how to make a `CMakeLists.txt` and `Findzfs.cmake` that works.

---

## Answer

### TLDR

I figured out-ish how to get it to link and stuff and I used `pkg_check_modules` in cmake.

### The saga

I'm gonna go ahead and assume the next punk that finds this post knows only as much as I did when I started this journey.

#### Pkg-Config

As it so happens theres a type of file called a [package config](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html) that takes the name `libzfs.pc` (or in general `libname.pc`). This package config file describes what dependencies libzfs has, what flags it needs to compile, and what flags it needs to link. Here's the `libzfs.pc` file for you to get a sense of it:

```
prefix=/root/zfs
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libzfs
Description: LibZFS library
Version: 2.1.0
URL: https://github.com/openzfs/zfs
Requires: libzfs_core
Requires.private: libcrypto zlib
Cflags: -I${includedir}/libzfs -I${includedir}/libspl
Libs: -L${libdir} -lzfs -lnvpair
Libs.private: -luutil -lm -pthread
```

This file tells me, for example, that I need to be using `-I /root/zfs/include/libzfs` and `-I /root/zfs/include/libspl` when I'm compiling against libzfs.

There's a tool (that's called `pkg-config` and that's not installed by default) that reads these configs and lets you ask things like "what are the include flags I need for this library" (`pkg-config --cflags-only-I <lib>`), or "what are the link flags I need for libzfs if I'm linking it statically" (`pkg-config --static --libs libzfs`), etc. This tool works by reading the .pc package config files. It looks in a couple standard locations and, of course, the zfs I built in my home directory is not a standard location.

In zfs the package configs are found in `prefix/lib/pkgconfig` (at least in 2.1.0. In 0.8.3 it's in a `prefix/share/pkgconfig`) where `prefix` in this case is `/root/zfs`. So to allow `pkg-config` to find `libzfs` and everything else, I had to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/root/zfs/lib/pkgconfig`.

#### Cmake

This tool is only half of what's needed. If you run the docker container - that I so graciously provided - you'll see that I'm using cmake. If you read the CMakeLists.txt you'll see that I call `find_package` and provide my own `Findblkid.cmake` and `Findudev.cmake` (or well they aren't mine, they're from ceph). As for the actual zfs portion I included everything.

There is another way.

Cmake is wise and provides a function called [pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html#command:pkg_check_modules) that uses `pkg-config` behind the scenes to figure out everything that's needed to link a package.

So I made a new CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(PackageTest C)

add_executable(prog example.c)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(ZFS REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libzfs)
target_link_libraries(prog PRIVATE PkgConfig::ZFS)
target_compile_definitions(prog PRIVATE _GNU_SOURCE)
```

As far as I can tell `_GNU_SOURCE` should be in `libzfs.pc` because the program wont compile without it. So, as far as I can tell, the maintainers made a mistake and not including it in `libzfs.pc` is a bug.

Comment: what's the gcc command? [Linking order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter)

Comment: Sometimes fixing one problem allows the tools to get further and find more problems. They are a lot better these days, but I remember the joys of winnowing compiler error lists down to 1 error, fixing that error and then being crushed by hundreds more (which would often turn out to have all been caused by 1 missing semicolon).

Comment: "undefined reference to `pow`" sounds like you're missing the math library as well.

Comment: The gcc command is `/usr/bin/cc   -rdynamic CMakeFiles/thread.dir/example.c.o  -o thread  ../zfs/lib/libnvpair.a ../zfs/lib/libuutil.a ../zfs/lib/libzfs.a ../zfs/lib/libzfsbootenv.a ../zfs/lib/libzfs_core.a ../zfs/lib/libzpool.a -lblkid -ludev -pthread`.  
I've tried linking in every different order I could think of.
@yano yeah but that goes away when I link udev and blkid.

Comment: as you've seen, slapping `pthread` on the end solves that problem.. the others are either because 1) libraries are out of order, or 2) you're omitting a library with those function definitions. If you're sure it's not 2, then it must be 1. Total guess here, but are the `uu*` functions in `libuutil.a`? Perhaps try moving that further towards the end of the list. The top answer in the question I linked has an excellent explanation for how the linker works and resolves unknown symbols. Any reason you're mixing`lib*.a`and `-l`?

Comment: How "cmake" tag is related to the question? CMake is NOT Make.

Comment: If `libzfs.a` uses symbols from `libuutil.a`, then `libzfs.a` should come **before** `libuutil.a`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/24675715#24675715. But your command line shows the opposite. Also note, that on Stack Overflow we expect information about the problem (a code, commands you execute, an error message) to be contained in the **question post** itself. Comments are not counted.

Comment: This question clearly isn't a duplicate. libzfs is a rather complicated library, and this question isn't addressed by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: @AlectoIrenePerez: When closed, the question wasn't about CMake at all (well, it had "cmake" tag, but neither the title nor the question body elaborated the connection with that tag). Now the title related with the tag, but the question body still contains just the error message **without the code**. That is, while the old duplicate is no longer suitable, I don't find the question being ready for reopen. Meanwhile, I have added the duplicate about using of `pkg-config` in CMake.

Comment: @FailureGod: In CMake there are several standard ways for include 3d-party library. Among them are `find_package`, `pkg_check_modules` and manual linking like described in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library). I doesn't find useful asking about linking a specific library without an **attempt** to use at least one of these approaches. Since you have tried "pure" `pkg_check_modules` (without `_GNU_SOURCE` option) approach, why don't describe it in the **question** part, along with the error it got? That way it could be a useful question.