# Run-time vs link-time linking of dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, dynamic, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dlopen

**tl;dr**

When the main application makes use of a dynamic library via `dlopen` and `dlsym`, does it need to be linked against it in any way?

---

Say I have a library like this,

- header

  ```cpp
  #pragma once
  void foo();
  ```
- implementation

  ```cpp
  #include "MyLib.hpp"
  #include <iostream>
  void foo() {
    std::cout << "Hello world, dynamic library speaking" << std::endl;
  }
  ```

that I compile via

```bash
g++ -fPIC -shared MyLib.cpp -o libMyLib.so
```

If the main application simply uses a symbol exported by that library, e.g.

```cpp
#include "MyLib.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "before calling foo" << std::endl;
    foo();
}
```

that means I have to link it against the library, i.e.

```bash
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -L. -lMyLib main.o -o main
```

There are two things that puzzle me:

- The first one is: why do I need to link `main.o` against `libMyLib.so`? I mean, the header `MyLib.hpp` already provides `main.cpp` with the signature of `foo`. What is the role of linking in this case?
- And what about the case that the main application uses `dlopen` to load the library and `dlsym` to load symbols from within it?

  My understanding is that it still needs to `#include "MyLib.hpp"`, for the simple fact that it needs to know how to interpret the output of `dlsym`, but does `main.o` need to be in anyway linked against the shared object?

Comment: 1. A prototype is enough for compilation,  but it has  nothing to do with linkage (though you may have the linker to create an executable with unresolved symbols (`-z nodefs`). 2. No

Comment: Note also that `g++ -L. -lMyLib main.o -o main` is _incorrect_. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894098

Comment: @EmployedRussian, you mean I should do `g++ -L. main.o -lMyLib -o main`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `dlopen` and `dlsym` you don't need the header file or the `foo` function prototype. You don't need it because the name in the library will not be plain `foo`.

The C++ compiler uses [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to be able to handle things like function overloads, and it's the *mangled* name you need to pass to `dlsym` to get a pointer to the function. The mangled names are very implementation-specific, and you need to examine the library to find out the actual mangled name.

As a workaround for the name mangling problem, you can declare the function *in the library* as `extern "C"`. This will, among other things, inhibit name mangling and you can pass the name `foo` to `dlsym`.

---

Also, if you use `dlopen` and `dlsym` you should not link with the library. That kind of defeats the purpose of your application doing the dynamic linking.

Comment: (Because you wrote _You don't need it because the name in the library will not be plain `foo`._) In the case of using `extern "C"`, should I still not `#include "MyLib.hpp"` in `main.cpp`?

Comment: @Enlico There's no need anyway, because the function prototype will not be used anyway. You must declare a new variable, which is a pointer to a function with the same return type and the same arguments, and then use that variable as assignment destination from the `dlsym` call. For example `void (*foo)() = dlsym(...)`

Comment: Yes, but isn't the header a way to get the type `void (*)()` from the library, rather than spelling it myself?

Comment: @Enlico Well possibly through `decltype(foo)`, but then you need to name the variable something other than `foo`.